# SQL command to get field of a maximum value, without making two select

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I'm starting to learn SQL and I'm working on this exercise: I have a "books" table which holds the info on every book (including price and genre ID). 
I need to get the name of the genre which has the highest average price. I suppose that I first need to group the prices by genre and then retrieve the name of the highest..

I know that I can get the results GENRE VS COST with the following:

```
select b.genre, 
       round(avg(b.price),2) as cost 
from books b 
group by b.genre;
```

My question is, to get the genre with the highest AVG price from that result, do I have to make:

```
select aux.genre 
from (
   select b.genre, 
          round(avg(b.price),2) as cost 
   from books b 
   group by b.genre
) aux 
where aux.cost = (select max(aux.cost) 
                  from (
                      select b.genre, 
                             round(avg(b.price),2) as cost 
                      from books l 
                      group by b.genre
                  ) aux);
```

Is it bad practice or isn't there another way? I get the correct result but I'm not confortable with creating two times the same selection.

I'm not using PL SQL so I can't use variables or anything like that..

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

On Sql server, you can use the avg aggragate inside the windowing function row_number

```
 with m as(
    select genre, 
         avg(price) cost, 
         row_number() over(order by avg(price) desc) rw
    from books
    group by genre
 )
 select * from m
 where rw=1
```

Comment: Are you sure you can nest an aggregate into the `over` clause of a windowing function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Works fine. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5990)

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's cool. Seems to work with Oracle and PostgreSQL as well. And when using `rank()` instead of `row_number()` ties are dealt with as well. Very elegant solution.

Comment: Yes.  Note that unlike the the solutions using top, this naturally includes ALL ties, so that if you have 3 genres with the the same 2nd place avg, and you wanted the top 3 averages, you would get 5 rows back (unique 1st place, 3 2nd place, unique 3rd place).

Comment: @jmoreno: but only when using `rank()` (or even `dense_rank()`)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the over command but from what I read it seems a nice solution. Basically, it sets the the row number in desc order of the average price, so when you write "where rw=1", it's like the select top 1 on MS-SQL, right?

Comment: Right.  The major difference is if there are more than 1 genre with the same average.

Answer (score 1):

```
with avg_price as (
   select b.genre, 
          round(avg(b.price),2) as cost 
   from books b 
   group by b.genre
)
select genre 
from avg_price
where cost = (select max(cost) from avg_price);
```

(This is ANSI standard SQL and works in all modern DBMS)

Comment: Wow, I've tried that "with.." part before but with no result. Is that like a "view"??

Comment: @AntónioCapelo: it's called a "common table expression" and yes you can think of it like a view "on the fly".

Comment: Nice! can you tell me if this is the "lightest" solution, or is there any quicker way to get those results? Just to see if I'm on the right track :)

Comment: @AntónioCapelo: maybe(!) jmoreno's solution might be quicker. But you will need to test with your data. Compare the execution plans for both solutions and you'll see which one is more efficient. But I don't expect a really big difference.

Answer (score 0):

In MS-SQL you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 genre, ROUND(AVG(price),2) AS cost 
FROM books
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(price),2) DESC
```

(the TOP clause is MS-SQL specific, but there are similiar constructs in other DBMS)

Comment: In fact, I'm using Oracle as dbms so It didn't work. I found that I need to use a rownum = 1 condition instead. But I'm not sure where to put it, as I'm using a group by...But I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1
  genre,
  avg(b.price) as cost
from books
group by
  genre
order by
  cost desc
```

Comment: This will only return a single row even if two genres have the same max cost (and it doesn't work with Oracle - but we don't know that for sure by now)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - If SQL Server then `TOP 1 WITH TIES` can be used.

Comment: guys, thanks for mention about this feature. My bad, forgot it.

Comment: will `where rownum = 1` work instead of `top 1` in this case?